# What kind of adapter is safe to use on my Samsung NP-R522 laptop?

Tags: laptop, adapter

I just got a Samsung NP R522 FS01HK from Hong Kong.

The power cord that came with the adapter doesn't fit into US outlets.  I looked around and the only power cord available for it that fits US plugs is [this one](http://www.samsungparts.com/Products/Parts_and_Accessories/PID-BN39-00185AG.aspx?oldpart=3903-000031) and it's discontinued.

What can I use with this laptop?  I think it requires a 60w adapter.  If I plug in any old universal 60w adapter will something go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Lenovo ThinkPad cord number 76H3516 will work and is available from Lenovo or other sources.

http://www.impactcomputers.com/76h3516.html   looks like a good price

[image]